# The network adapter could not establish the connection - Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, tomcat6

I wrote a servlet program and I want it to connect to my Oracle database but its giving me an error. I am using Eclipse Helios, Tomcat 6.0.37, Oracle 11g (11.2.0.1.0), ojdbc6.jar(added in run configuration of the Server project). I am able to connect to the database through the SQL Plus interface and even can start a connection from Eclipse's database development perspective. But when i am trying to connect through my servlet I am getting the error. For my servlet i am using the port number 9090 and for the database the default 1521.

```
java.sql.SQLException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:412)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:221)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.collegenotificationsystem.RegistrationServlet.doGet(RegistrationServlet.java:43)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:359)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:422)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:672)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:237)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1042)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:301)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:141)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:123)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:337)
    ... 26 more
```

This is my code for establishing the connection:

`Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(                  "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","username","password");`

I tried executing the lsnrctl stat command and this was the result:

```
LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 03-AUG-2013 16:08
:46

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                03-AUG-2013 12:14:19
Uptime                    0 days 3 hr. 54 min. 28 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\Owner\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\lis
tener.ora
Listener Log File         c:\app\owner\diag\tnslsnr\Owner-PC\listener\alert\log.
xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orcl.168.1.56" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclXDB.168.1.56" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

These are the contents of my tnsnames.ora file:

```
LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.168.1.56)
    )
  )
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell us the connection information you use in eclipse to connect to this database instance?. A screenshot of the connection parameters would definitely help

Comment: I have to ask the obvious question: is the Servlet running on the same machine as the Oracle DB?

Comment: If it's cloud based then check database id.

Answer (score 13):

I had the similar issue. its resolved for me with a simple command.

```
lsnrctl start
```

The Network Adapter exception is caused because:

1. The database host name or port number is wrong (OR)
2. The database TNSListener has not been started. The TNSListener may be started with the `lsnrctl` utility.

Try to start the listener using the command prompt:

1. Click Start, type `cmd` in the search field, and when `cmd` shows up in the list of options, right click it and select ‘Run as Administrator’.
2. At the Command Prompt window, type `lsnrctl start` without the quotes and press Enter.
3. Type `Exit` and press Enter.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Did you see the output of `lsnrctl status` that Ash posted?

Comment: What about on macOS? I'm getting `lsnrctl: command not found`

Answer (score 5):

First check your listener is on or off.
Go to net manager then Local -> service naming -> orcl.
Then change your HOST NAME and put your PC name.
Now go to LISTENER and change the HOST and put your PC name.

Comment: I search out almost whole of that Internet! But this solved my problem. +1 By the way does this `hostname` has to be PC name? or is it just a convention or something?

Comment: hostname should be different than PC name.

Answer (score 0):

Chances that DB Listener went down and application is unable to connect to the Database. Listener should be started to fix this.