# JBoss and Oracle 12c : datasource bound successfully but cannot connect

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jboss

I have installed JBoss 7.1 in my machine (and just FYI I have deployed a Liferay instance in mySQL successfully). I have properly installed Oracle 12c in my server and I can connect with sqlplus and make queries successfully. However, when I switch to Oracle Datasource the server fails. I have followed the following steps :

- Created a folder `$JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/liferay/portal/main` where I placed `ojdbc6.jar` and the suitable file `module.xml`
- Edited the file `standalone.xml`, by defining the driver and the datasource as below :

  jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:LIFERAY
      oracle
      
            
            
      

  ...

     oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
- I also set the following properties in the file portal-ext.properties

  jdbc.default.jndi.name=java:/jdbc/OracleLiferayPool
  hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

However, when I start Jboss and run the jboss-cli to test the datasource I get the following error :

```
"failure-description" => "JBAS010440: failed to invoke operation: JBAS010447: Connection is not valid"
```

Notice that I have priorly connected to the oracle database (testing thin driver) with the following tool :
http://dbasolved.com/2014/02/21/oracle-jdbc-connection-tester/

I can also connect to the oracle database with sqlplus (so it must be Jboss configuration error)

The logs of the Jboss when failing to connect are the following :

```
    WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 97) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
    at         org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:288)
    at     org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:246)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:781)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:344)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:397)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:365)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:329)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:368)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:464)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:139)
        at com.liferay.portal.dao.jdbc.util.DataSourceWrapper.getConnection(DataSourceWrapper.java:39) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.afterPropertiesSet(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:163) [spring-jdbc.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:630) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:441) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:982) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:878) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:484) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1327) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1327) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710) [spring-context.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:410) [spring-context.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282) [spring-web.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204) [spring-web.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [spring-web.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:227) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web.jar:7.3.2.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web.jar:7.3.2.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web.jar:7.3.2.Final-redhat-2]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:419) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:260)
        ... 68 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:375) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:422) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:678) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:238) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1054) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:308) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        ... 73 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:209) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:123) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:353) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        ... 78 more
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 97) JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAutoProxyCreator#0' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'counterTransactionAdvice' while setting bean property 'methodInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'counterTransactionAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'counterTransactionManager' while setting bean property 'platformTransactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'counterTransactionManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'counterHibernateSessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'counterHibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1327) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710) [spring-context.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:410) [spring-context.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282) [spring-web.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204) [spring-web.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [spring-web.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:227) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web.jar:7.3.2.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web.jar:7.3.2.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web.jar:7.3.2.Final-redhat-2]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'counterTransactionAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'counterTransactionManager' while setting bean property 'platformTransactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'counterTransactionManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'counterHibernateSessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'counterHibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1327) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'counterTransactionManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'counterHibernateSessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'counterHibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:630) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:441) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:982) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:878) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:484) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        ... 36 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'counterHibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:169) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2863) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2859) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860) [spring-orm.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779) [spring-orm.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.hibernate.PortalHibernateConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(PortalHibernateConfiguration.java:64) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211) [spring-orm.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        ... 55 more
```

I have made the most debugging I could and I cannot understand where is my error.
Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got resolved, there was no problem of inconsistency between Oracle 12c and JBoss (or Hibernate).

I checked both the following :

```
telnet localhost 1521
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
```

and

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 1521
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

and with further debugging I concluded that Oracle was only listening on the IPv4 address only and not in the IPv6, and localhost was being resolved to the IPv6 address.
This was due to the /etc/hosts file which included the below records :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

So, I changed the hosts file as below

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

and now JBoss can connect successfully at Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Check if your `TNSListener` started ([The network adapter could not establish the connection - Oracle 11g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037440/the-network-adapter-could-not-establish-the-connection-oracle-11g)).

Try to change `localhost` to the network name of your PC.

Comment: TNSListener is up and running "tnsping liferay" returns :
Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost.localdomain)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = LIFERAY)))
OK (0 msec)

Comment: Also, the change of localhost to my network name did not change the behaviour at all.

Comment: Can you connect using this `telnet localhost:1521` ?

Comment: yes, I can connect through `telnet localhost 1521`