# spring framework jdbcCan not Get Jdbc Connection Exception

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc

Actually i am trying to connect the oracle database with Spring and i am using spring-servlet.xml file specified below containing oracle database configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-   instance"xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

 <!-- telling container to take care of annotations stuff -->
 <context:annotation-config />

 <!-- declaring base package -->
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.bank" />

 <!-- adding view resolver to show jsp's on browser -->
 <bean id="viewResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
 <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>

  <!-- declare beans -->


  <bean id="PersionalDetailsdao" class="com.bank.dao.PersionalDetailsDaoImpl" />
 <bean id="persionalService" class="com.bank.services.PersionalDetailsServiceImpl" />


 <!-- declare datasource bean -->
  <bean id="dataSource"
   class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:orcl" />
   <property name="username" value="SYSTEM" />
   <property name="password" value="SangamOne123" />
 </bean>
 </beans>
```

But after running the application i am getting the following exception .

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:333)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:404)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getConnectionInstance(OracleDriver.java:468)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:314)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at  org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverMana gerDataSource.java:173)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:113)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:572)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:786)
   at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:842)
   at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:850)
   at com.bank.dao.PersionalDetailsDaoImpl.insertData(PersionalDetailsDaoImpl.java:30)
   at com.bank.services.PersionalDetailsServiceImpl.insertData(PersionalDetailsServiceImpl.java:18)
  at com.bank.controller.PersionalDetailsController.inserData(PersionalDetailsController.java:93)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037440/the-network-adapter-could-not-establish-the-connection-oracle-11g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether  your listener is up or not. If not , start listner using cmd

Comment: I tried the lsnrctl start command but still it is showing the same exception .